# Insert javascript method inside html paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

<p id="demo"><script>Date()</script></p>    <!-- here I want to put the output of Date() method -->

</body>
</html>
```

I know that I can do something like:

```
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
```

But I'd like to know if there's a way to do that inside the paragraph directly.

Comment: document.write will do this as long and it's safe as long as it's during the initial load

Comment: @JuanMendes Post that as an answer.

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks! it works! but what do you mean for "will do this as long and it's safe as long as it's during the initial load "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) to write content to the HTML directly from JavaScript.

```html
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

<p id="demo"><script>document.write( Date())</script></p>
```

**NOTE**
Calling `document.write()` after the initial HTML has been parsed [will cause the entire HTML to be discarded and a new document will be created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#notes). This is only safe to be called while the document is being parsed.

---

Example of calling document.write after document has been processed

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.write("Written after HTML doc was closed");
}, 5000);
```

```html
<h1> Hello </h1>
<p> I will disappear after document.write is called</p>
```